# Can someone explain what does PduR mean in AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

In many block diagrams of AUTOSAR specification they use the term PduR.

But there is no such kind of module in AUTOSAR Schema.

Can someone explain what does PduR mean?

Comment: Do you mean PduR? as it is  Basic Software Module of the Communication Services. PDUR - (Protocol Data Unit Router)

Comment: Yes I want to ask about PDUR

Comment: it is a very vast topic. you can refer to : https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/3-0/AUTOSAR_SWS_PDU_Router.pdf  Find PDUR in topic section and you will have all the specifications list about it. or do you want me to short it up and post as answer?

Comment: So PDUR is not having any relation with SWC right?

Comment: It has. read down the link i have sent you. It will help you to clear your doubts. under topic PDUR.

Comment: Sorry, but the relation between software-components and the PduR is **very** indirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PduR is the abbreviation for “Pdu Router”. The PduR is a basic software module in the AUTOSAR stack.

A typical purpose of the PduR is to accept Pdus from a lower-layer module and deliver it to a higher-level module or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

The PDU Router module is a central module of the AUTOSAR communication stack. its main purpose is to provide an abstractions from bus-dependent communication modules (CAN , Flexray , ETH , LIN , ....etc) and is responsible for the Routing of I-PDUs from (BUS_if) to com and vise versa ,Routing to/from TP Modules, perform Gateway Functionality

Answer (score 1):

PDUR is a Router of pdu which routes the pdu from lower layer to upper layer and vice versa, pdur lies in service layer of BSW, followed by com.